# Can one find an approximation to the closest positive definite matrix?

Tags: matrices, statistics, covariance, correlation, positive-definite

I understand that the closest (in the Frobenius norm) positive semidefinite matrix can be found via various algorithms such as projection.

1. Is it possible to find the closest positive definite matrix?
2. It's an open set so I am thinking that the nearest matrix does not exist. Are there any efficient ways of finding an approximation?

I am guessing you would find the closest positive semidefinite matrix and then permute the diagonal elements slightly to force it to be positive definite.

Comment: To find the closest you need a notion of distance. If you tell us that then perhaps there is an answer. The method you are describing can be applied but you need a slight modification. Instead of permuting the diagonal elements you can simply add a small $\epsilon > 0$ in a every zero eigenvalue.

Comment: I do apologize, Its closest in Frobenius norm. Ah yeah I thought as much thank you.

Comment: If the case of the Frobenius norm, you can find the closest positive semi definite. If it happens to  be positive definite then that's the answer, otherwise you can tweak the eigenvalues as I said above.